# Trying to create a function that takes a list and returns a list of all of all elements identical to its first element, but my function isn't working

Tags: list, haskell

Specifically one for Strings. So it would take `["so", "what", "and", "so", "for" "so"]` and return `["so", "so", "so"]`. My problem is that my function returns a list identical to the one inputted.

Here's all relevant code:

```
lookAhead :: [String] -> String
lookAhead [] = []
lookAhead (c:cs) = c

groupFirst :: [String] -> [String]
groupFirst [] = []
groupFirst (x:xs) 
    | lookAhead xs == x  = x : (groupFirst ((lookAhead xs):(tail xs)))
    | lookAhead xs /= x  = x : (groupFirst xs)
    | lookAhead xs == [] = x : []
```

Comment: One way of debugging is to think carefully about what happens at each step when you pass in your input. You can start with `["so","what"]`. If you still have trouble then you should break your solution down into smaller parts

Comment: If `x` is the first element of the list at each recursive step, what do you want to compare it with? How many different cases do you need to deal with in this comparison? When do you want to include `x` in the result list?

Answer (score 6):

`trail` as head-element-equality-predicated `filter`:

```
trail :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
trail []       = []
trail (x : xs) = x : filter (== x) xs
```

`trailBy` using [*Schwartzian transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

```
trailBy :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
trailBy _ []        = []
trailBy f (x1 : xs) = let x1f = f x1
                      in  x1 : filter (\ x -> f x == x1f) xs
```

`trail  =  trailBy id`, where `id x = x`, Haskell's identity function.

Comment: Even though they don't cause a crash here, `head` and `tail` are evil. Avoid them. Handle both cases via pattern matching and then decide what you are going to do when given an empty list. (This also applies to the other answers.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is that within `groupFirst`, you're iterating over the list and comparing the list tail (which has type `[String]`) to the head of the list (`String`). So every comparison will be matched by the second guard, where you end up building an identical list.

You need to find a way to make the first string accessible for comparison so you can iterate over the list without changing the function call (we want something of the form `f strList`, not `f firstStr strList`). One way to solve this problem by having your function call another function, passing the head of the list as an argument:

```
lookAhead :: [String] -> [String]
lookAhead [] = []
lookAhead (x:xs) = x : check x xs

check :: String -> [String] -> [String]
check str = foldr (\x acc -> if x == str then x:acc else acc) []
```

Comment: The OP had it right by using pattern matching on the list argument instead of `head` and `tail`; don't change that.

Comment: `lookAhead` crashes when given an empty list. (The other two answers are lucky to escape this fate because their boolean tests are never actually applied when the list is empty).

Answer (score 1):

The `lookAhead` function returns the first element and that value is being updated recursively in the `groupFirst` function. One way you could do it is using a list comprehension:

```
groupFirst :: [String] -> [String] 
groupFirst [] = []
groupFirst list = [x | x <- list, head list == x]
```

Comment: Even though they don't cause a crash here, `head` and `tail` are evil. Avoid them. Handle both cases via pattern matching and then decide what you are going to do when given an empty list. (This also applies to the other answers.)